# screen shot in android

Tags: android

Am working on screen capture in android mobile..
As of now am able to capture my application screen..
But my requirement is my application should run in background and should capture the main menu screen and home screen and etc..

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. How are you capturing your app screen?

Comment: I hope that is not possible. It would be a security violation if apps could make screen shots of other apps.